# Vlookup not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

```
A column      Bcolumn    Ccolumn      Dcolumn
Jack          A         John          =vlookup(A1,A1:C4,2)
Jason         B         John
John          C         Jason
                        Jack
```

When I press enter I see

```
John - A
John - B
Jason - C
```

whatever is present in column B is being returned, what i want to do is get

```
John - C
John- C
Jason -B
Jack - A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B4,2)
```

In fact, you better use absolute references, otherwise the lookup range will get messed up when you copy the formula down.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,2)
```

But really, I would advise dropping `VLOOKUP` in favour of `INDEX` and `MATCH`, which is way more flexible:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to force it to use an exact match with a last false parameter, and also set the look up range to be absolute if you are filling the formula down to D4.

=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,2,false)